# JS script doesn't work because of if else blocks

Tags: javascript, android

I am making a simple prototype calculator for a game that involves various damage calculations under specific conditions. Because this game involves some precision and we often need calculations on the spot, I've decided to try convert this into an actual app for android phones using [Appsgeyser](http://www.appsgeyser.com/) instead of going online to some dummy webpage I'd set up for a basic form calculator.

However my javascript skills are also basic, but enough for this little project of mine. I realized later on how awful my syntax is and why people have criticized it, but since I don't know how to improve it I can only ask people to help me out find the error.

The IF / ELSE blocks fail and I cannot see why.

```
<script>
function showDiv() {
var dmgpct = 0;
var dmginc2 = 0.00;
var arminc = 0.00;
var critinc = 0.00;
var critinc2 = 0;
var splashdmg2 = 0;
var splashinc = 0.00;
var critchance = parseInt(document.getElementById('critchance').value);
var critdmg = document.getElementById('critdmg').value;
var splashdmg = parseInt(document.getElementById('splashdmg').value);
var armor = document.getElementById('armortype').value;
var armoramount = document.getElementById('armoramt').value;
var damage = document.getElementById('dmgtype').value;
var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('mindmg').value);
var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('maxdmg').value);
var dmginc = parseInt(document.getElementById('dmginc').value);
var dmg_done = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
var try_crit = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - critchance + 1) + critchance);

document.getElementById('result').style.display = "block";

if(damage == "Normal" && armor == "Medium")
{
dmginc2 = parseFloat(dmginc * 0.01 + 1.50);
arminc = parseFloat(dmginc2 - armoramount * 0.05);
dmgpct = Math.floor(dmg_done * arminc);
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Damage Roll: " + dmg_done;
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = "Damage Boost: " + arminc.toFixed(2) + "%";
    if (try_crit <= critchance)
    {
    critinc = parseFloat(critdmg * 0.01);
    critinc2 = parseInt(dmgpct*critinc);
    splashinc = parseFloat(splashdmg * 0.01);
    splashdmg2 = Math.floor(critinc2 * splashinc);
    document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = "<b>CRITICAL DAMAGE: " + critinc2 + "</b>";
    document.getElementById('test4').innerHTML = "<b>Splash Damage Dealt: " + splashdmg2 + "</b>";
    }
    else
    {
    splashinc = parseFloat(splashdmg * 0.01);
    splashdmg2 = Math.floor(dmgpct * splashinc);
    document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = "<b>Total Damage Dealt: " + dmgpct + "</b>";
    document.getElementById('test4').innerHTML = "<b>Splash Damage Dealt: " + splashdmg2 + "</b>";
    }
}
else if(damage == "Normal" && armor == "Heavy")
{
dmginc2 = parseFloat(dmginc * 0.01 + 0.50);
arminc = parseFloat(dmginc2 - armoramount * 0.05);
dmgpct = Math.floor(dmg_done * arminc);
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Damage Roll: " + dmg_done;
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = "Damage Boost: " + arminc.toFixed(2) + "%";
    if (try_crit <= critchance)
    {
    critinc = parseFloat(critdmg * 0.01);
    critinc2 = parseInt(dmgpct*critinc);
    splashinc = parseFloat(splashdmg * 0.01);
    splashdmg2 = Math.floor(critinc2 * splashinc);
    document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = "<b>CRITICAL DAMAGE: " + critinc2 + "</b>";
    document.getElementById('test4').innerHTML = "<b>Splash Damage Dealt: " + splashdmg2 + "</b>";
    }
    else
    {
    splashinc = parseFloat(splashdmg * 0.01);
    splashdmg2 = Math.floor(dmgpct * splashinc);
    document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = "<b>Total Damage Dealt: " + dmgpct + "</b>";
    document.getElementById('test4').innerHTML = "<b>Splash Damage Dealt: " + splashdmg2 + "</b>";
    }
}
else if(damage == "Normal" && armor == "Light")
{
dmginc2 = parseFloat(dmginc * 0.01 + 1.00);
arminc = parseFloat(dmginc2 - armoramount * 0.05);
dmgpct = Math.floor(dmg_done * arminc);
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Damage Roll: " + dmg_done;
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = "Damage Boost: " + arminc.toFixed(2) + "%";
    if (try_crit <= critchance)
    {
    critinc = parseFloat(critdmg * 0.01);
    critinc2 = parseInt(dmgpct*critinc);
    splashinc = parseFloat(splashdmg * 0.01);
    splashdmg2 = Math.floor(critinc2 * splashinc);
    document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = "<b>CRITICAL DAMAGE: " + critinc2 + "</b>";
    document.getElementById('test4').innerHTML = "<b>Splash Damage Dealt: " + splashdmg2 + "</b>";
    }
    else
    {
    splashinc = parseFloat(splashdmg * 0.01);
    splashdmg2 = Math.floor(dmgpct * splashinc);
    document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = "<b>Total Damage Dealt: " + dmgpct + "</b>";
    document.getElementById('test4').innerHTML = "<b>Splash Damage Dealt: " + splashdmg2 + "</b>";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide a small, self-contained example demonstrating the problem using something like http://www.jsfiddle.net (hint: Javascript supports multiple if...else without an issue)

Comment: What inputs are giving you trouble? What happens instead of what you expect? What do you see when you single-step through the code in the debugger built into your browser? What do you expect to happen if the user selects `damage` that isn't `"Normal"`? Separately: You can use whatever code indentation you like, but when asking for help, pick one of the standard readable ones, please, and use that. See http://jsbeautifier.org and similar.

Comment: well most of the code is copy-pasted with only a few changed values. i guess the problem is around the else ifs

Comment: Try setting data inside the _if_ blocks, then applying the data afterwards

Comment: You say "only the first if works and the two other else if don't". Can you elaborate? What behaviour are you seeing that you aren't expecting? You've posted a lot of code that we're unable to actually run ourselves, so it's extremely hard to offer anything useful when we don't even know what you're expecting to happen differently. For a start, what inputs are you using, and what outputs are you getting that you're not expecting?

Comment: It was solved, I was missing a closing bracket. Check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a well formated and indented code, you can easily see that a closing bracket is missing at the end of the function ...

And independently of the layout, you should REALLY improve it's readability, that's hell to read.

Comment: You're right, I am typing it in a small html online editor. But that's no excuse. Thank you that fixed the code